# Why is my latest code overriding the rest of my code

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have a page with timers. the code for my latest timer only functions properly. but the rest of the timers don't such as the 10 minute timer. It only shows you the set time for the timer. Is my latest code overriding my other code? Are variables being mixed between the two timers? I'm planning on adding several timers to the page, but I got stuck when this happened.

Link to code: http://jsfiddle.net/vtoLx02j/2/

```
<body>
    
    <div id="1Div">
    
    <h4>Question goes here?</h4>
    
      <input type="text"id="name1"/>
    
      <button onclick="myFunction1()" id="button0" class="button3">Enter</button>
    
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="2Div" style="display:none;">
            <h4 id=typeE>How much time do you think you need in minutes?</h4>
            <button onclick="myFunction2()" id="button1" class="button3">10 minutes</button>
            <button onclick="myFunction3()" id="button2" class="button3">20 minutes</button>
            
    </div>
    
    <script>
      function myFunction1(){
        document.getElementById("1Div").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("2Div").style.display="block";
    }
    </script>
    
    <script>
      function myFunction2(){
        document.getElementById("2Div").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("timer10").style.display="block";
      }
    </script>
    
    <script>
      function myFunction3(){
        document.getElementById("2Div").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("timer20").style.display="block";
      }
    </script>
    
    
    <div id="timer10" style="display:none">
    
    <script>
        function startTimer10(duration10, display10) {
        var timer10 = duration10, minutes10, seconds10;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes10 = parseInt(timer10 / 60, 10);
            seconds10 = parseInt(timer10 % 60, 10);
    
            minutes10 = minutes10 < 10 ? "0" + minutes10 : minutes10;
            seconds10 = seconds10 < 10 ? "0" + seconds10 : seconds10;
    
            display10.textContent = minutes10 + ":" + seconds10;
    
            if (--timer10 < 0) {
                timer10 = duration10;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    window.onload = function () {
        var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,
            display10 = document.querySelector('#time10');
        startTimer10(tenMinutes, display10);
    };
    </script>
     
     <body>
        
        <center><div><span id="time10">10:00</span></div></center>
        
    </body>
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="timer20" style="display:none">
        <script>
        function startTimer20(duration20, display20) {
        var timer20 = duration20, minutes20, seconds20;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes20 = parseInt(timer20 / 60, 10);
            seconds20 = parseInt(timer20 % 60, 10);
    
            minutes20 = minutes20 < 10 ? "0" + minutes20 : minutes20;
            seconds20 = seconds20 < 10 ? "0" + seconds20 : seconds20;
    
            display20.textContent = minutes20 + ":" + seconds20;
    
            if (--timer20 < 0) {
                timer20 = duration20;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    
    window.onload = function () {
        var twentyMinutes = 60 * 20,
            display20 = document.querySelector('#time20');
        startTimer20(twentyMinutes, display20);
    };
    </script>
     
     <body>
        
        <center><div><span id="time20">20:00</span></div></center>
        
    </body>
    </div>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: FYI you cant have multiple `body` tags in a document, see usage here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp

Comment: Would you mind [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if i have solved your question ?

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your advice, it helped a lot!

Comment: @hp3393 Happy to help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply combine all your `functions` into single `startTimer()` function.

I am not sure why you are `repeating` your `code` again and again to **achieve** the same results. Its good to have *less code but have the same results*.

So here's is what i have done and simplified your code.

1. I have combined both `timers` into **one** `function`
2. You do not need to use display `none` and `block` again on show time duration
3. When you click on the `timer` just pass the `minutes` to the timer function and the span will start displaying the time remaining
4. You do no need two span to display timer separately you can do all that in one `span`
5. You were using `script` tag so many times which are unnecessary
6. Both timers are working perfectly with less code and same results.

You can have multiple `timers` now you just need to pass the `minutes` to your `startTimer()` function and timer will start from the given time.

**Live Demo**

```js
//Start timer
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

//1
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("1Div").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("2Div").style.display = "block";
}

//10 Minutes
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("2Div").style.display = "none";
  var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,
  display10 = document.querySelector('#timerDuration');
  startTimer(tenMinutes, display10);
}

//20 minutes
function myFunction3() {
  document.getElementById("2Div").style.display = "none";
  var twentyMinutes = 60 * 20,
  display20 = document.querySelector('#timerDuration');
  startTimer(twentyMinutes, display20);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="1Div">
    <h4>Question goes here?</h4>

    <input type="text" id="name1" />

    <button onclick="myFunction1()" id="button0" class="button3">Enter</button>
  </div>
  <div id="2Div" style="display:none;">
    <h4 id=typeE>How much time do you think you need in minutes?</h4>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()" id="button1" class="button3">10 minutes</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction3()" id="button2" class="button3">20 minutes</button>
  </div>
  <center>
    <div><span id="timerDuration"></span></div>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: is there a way for a div to block the timer when it ends?

Comment: @hp3393 Yes! You need to use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)  function and to check if time is ended then use stop the interval. Something like `if timer == 0{clearInterval()}`